# Can't install pyspark on PyCharm

Tags: python, pyspark, pycharm

I am trying to install `pyspark` on PyCharm but I end up with the following error:

```
Collecting pyspark
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/37/98/244399c0daa7894cdf387e7007d5e8b3710a79b67f3fd991c0b0b644822d/pyspark-2.4.3.tar.gz

    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Could not import pypandoc - required to package PySpark
    Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/pypandoc/: [Errno 60] Operation timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'pypandoc' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/: [Errno 60] Operation timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or working download links found for pypandoc
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/m6/x3v1x7255lv_w_vsp0zz_jw8hvmgc7/T/pycharm-packaging/pyspark/setup.py", line 224, in <module>
        'Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: PyPy']
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 717, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 782, in resolve
        replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 784, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 673, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pypandoc')
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/m6/x3v1x7255lv_w_vsp0zz_jw8hvmgc7/T/pycharm-packaging/pyspark/
```

I've tried to install it through *Preferences -> Project Interpreter -> Click on the '+' -> search for `pyspark` -> click install package*

Relevant packages already installed:

`pip v19.1.1` (latest)
`setuptools v41.0.1` (latest) 
`ez-setup v0.9` (latest)

Note that I am able to install other packages.

Can someone shed some light here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error indicates:

```
No local packages or working download links found for pypandoc
```

You should first install `pypandoc` and then try to install `pyspark` package.